# Allow admin to create a new column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, database-design

What I'm trying to do is allow an admin to create a questionnaire. 
Every time a user writes a review for a product they must also fill out a questionnaire. This is for an educational simulation.

I'm currently using Visual Studio an am developing an ASP.NET MVC3 Website in C#.
I also use/have SQL Server 2008 and SQL Management Studio.

I'm having trouble thinking about the best way to do this.

Right now my solution is to say "You can ask up to 10 questions" and then have a 'Questions' table in my database and store all answers with each review and have 10 'Answer' columns per review.

What would be even better is if I can somehow allow the admin to ask as many questions as they'd like and add more columns to my database table as needed. Is there any way to do this?

Or is there a better way to design my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't very normalized.

You should have a table with one record for each question/answer pair.

Comment: Would you suggest another table to hold the questions? Then when a user leaves a review display each question along with a text box, and then when they submit save each question and its answer in the question/answer table that also contains an ID that points back to the review it's for?

Answer (score 2):

Just give yourself a child table `Answers` that has a foreign key to `Questions`.  Then you can have as many answers as you want.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to have a table to store the `Questions`, and a separate table to store the `Answers`. The `Answers` table can then have a foreign key to the record in `Questions` it's answering.